# JsPrettier on Sublime text [OSX]

Tags: sublimetext3, jsprettier

I tried to install auto_format_on_save using JSPrettier on my Sublime text.
But everytime i'm saving my file, i get :

```
------------------
 JsPrettier ERROR 
------------------

Prettier reported the following error(s):

env: node: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 127
```

For what i've read, it is because i'm using `oh-my-zh` and `nvm` but i don't succeed to configure my setup files properly.

Please help

> which node ::  /Users/mymac/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting `node_path` in your `JsPrettier - User settings` to point to the absolute path output by `$ which node` (for whatever version of Node you want the plugin to use).

You might also try setting `prettier_cli_path` similarly to the output of `$ which prettier`.

I pulled this from Settings in the extension docs:

> **node_path** (default: ***empty***) If Sublime Text has problems resolving the absolute path to node, you can set a custom path here.
>
> > nvm users must set an appropriate absolute `node_path` (and absolute `prettier_cli_path`), according to the runtime environment.

https://github.com/jonlabelle/SublimeJsPrettier#settings